# Print image with Microsoft report viewer

Tags: reportviewer, reportviewer2008

I am trying to get the Microsoft Report Viewer to print out the images in my reports.

I have a report that have a company logo banner accross the top of the report.
It shows up when I look at the report viewer, but the image doesnt show up when I look at the print layout view or when I print it out on paper.

I am not sure what to check here. I am not very familiar with the report viewer.
Anyone can give any clue on where to check regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, I've seen this but it's been a while. Have you checked out to see if the image is embedded? This may help - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251715(VS.80).aspx

IIRC one has to change the default properties of the image. Please note I'm going off of memory here :)